# .NET: WebBrowser, WebClient, WebRequest, HTTPWebRequest... ARGH!

Tags: c#, .net, system.net

In the System.Net namespace, there are very many different classes with similar names, such as:

- WebBrowser and WebClient
- WebRequest and HTTPWebRequest
- WebResponse and HTTPWebResponse

Those are the main ones I'm curious about.

**What is each one's function? How are they different from one another?**

Also, in what cases would you use which?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

**WebBrowser** is actually in the System.Windows.Forms namespace and is a visual control that you can add to a form.  It is primarily a wrapper around the Internet Explorer browser (MSHTML).  It allows you to easily display and interact programmatically with a web page.  You call the Navigate method passing a web URL, wait for it to complete downloading and display and then interact with the page using the object model it provides.

**HttpWebRequest** is a concrete class that allows you to request in code any sort of file over HTTP.  You usually receive it as a stream of bytes.  What you do with it after that is up to your application.

**HttpWebResponse** allows you to process the response from a web server that was previously requested using HttpWebRequest.

**WebRequest** and **WebResponse** are the abstract base classes that the HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse inherit from.  You can't create these directly.  Other classes that inherit from these include Ftp and File classes.

**WebClient** I have always seen as a nice helper class that provides simpler ways to, for example, download or upload a file from a web url.  (eg DownloadFile and DownloadString methods). I have heard that it actually uses HttpWebRequest / HttpWebResponse behind the scenes for certain methods.

If you need more fine grained control over web requests and responses, HttpWebRequest / HttpWebResponse are probably the way to go.  Otherwise WebClient is generally simpler and will do the job.

Comment: You're actually right, done.  Are you really 12?  You write more clearly than most people 3 times your age!  It's great to see younger people on StackOverflow.  If you want to be a programmer later on you'll learn a huge amount of **good** information here.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know of any System.Net.WebBrowser, but WebClient is basically a class that lets you easily download files (including html pages) from the web into memory or even directly to file.  A basic code sample looks like this:

```
string html;
using (var wc = new WebClient())
{
    html = wc.DownloadString("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780679/");
}
```

You can do a lot with WebClient, but there are some limitations.  If you need to do some serious web scraping, you'll need to get lower level.  That's where the HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse come in.  You can use them to send any request a normal web browser might send, in any sequence.  For example, you may need to authenticate with a web site before you can request the page you really want, and WebClient might not be able to do that.  HttpWebRequest will.

Now, there is one other option.  System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser is a *control* designed to place on a form.  It basically wraps the engine used in Internet Explorer to provide all the capabilities of a web browser.  You need to be careful using this for general scraping:  it's not portable (bad for mono), uses a lot of resources, has similar security issues as running a full browser, and has side-effects such as potentially leaking popup windows.  The control is best used in a form to connect to a specific known web resource. For example, you may have a Windows Forms app for sale, and web app where you sell it for download.  You might provide a WebBrowser control that shows a few pages on this web site specifically intended for view in your app that allows users to purchase in-app upgrades.

Answer (score 2):

WebRequest and WebResponse are abstract classes.  HTTPWebRequest and HTTPWebResponse are implementations of them.

Answer (score 0):

WebClient is quite a neat way to fetch the HTML page.
Here is the code snippet to download a response string.

```
   string getHtmlPageUsingWC(string strQuery, System.Net.WebProxy proxy = null)
    {
        string strResponse = String.Empty;
        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            wc.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            IWebProxy wp = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
            wp.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            wc.Proxy = wp;
            wc.Headers.Add("Accept-Language:en");

            NameValueCollection nvc = new NameValueCollection();
            nvc.Add("q", strQuery);

            wc.QueryString.Add(nvc);

            try
            {
                strResponse = wc.DownloadString(m_strURL);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                strResponse = "Request Declined: " + ex.Message;
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        return strResponse;
    }
```