# HTTP POST Request by code behind

Tags: .net, http, webforms, http-post

There's an external webservice and there's my page in .NET webforms.
I need to call this webservice from my page passing parameters by POST.
Some of these parameters I need to fill in code behind. Including a `input type="file"`.

My question is:
How do I post request to webservice with POST method?
 Is it possible through code-behind, or I will have to submit by JavaScript?

Comment: have a look at the WebClient class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx

Comment: Are you just looking for the `HttpWebRequest` class?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Marvin and David answer-comments:

It's possible by using `WebClient` or `HttpWebRequest`.
As far as I understood, WebClient inherits HttpWebRequest, providing more simply way to code.

Some examples:

```
Using client As New Net.WebClient
    Dim reqparm As New Specialized.NameValueCollection
    reqparm.Add("param1", "somevalue")
    reqparm.Add("param2", "othervalue")
    Dim responsebytes = client.UploadValues(someurl, "POST", reqparm)
    Dim responsebody = (New Text.UTF8Encoding).GetString(responsebytes)
End Using
```

Reference: [Sending HTTP POST with System.Net.WebClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8222092/sending-http-post-with-system-net-webclient)

```
string postData = Console.ReadLine();
using (System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
    wc.Headers.Add("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    // Upload the input string using the HTTP 1.0 POST method.
    byte[] byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
    byte[] byteResult= wc.UploadData("http://targetwebiste","POST",byteArray);
    // Decode and display the result.
    Console.WriteLine("\nResult received was {0}",
                      Encoding.ASCII.GetString(byteResult));
}
```

Reference: [Send POST with WebClient.DownloadString in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8290390/send-post-with-webclient-downloadstring-in-c-sharp)

Other references here in StackOverflow:
[.NET: WebBrowser, WebClient, WebRequest, HTTPWebRequest... ARGH!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780679/net-webbrowser-webclient-webrequest-httpwebrequest-argh?rq=1)
[WebClient vs. HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694388/webclient-vs-httpwebrequest-httpwebresponse)